# Ember.js consuming REST Services

Tags: web-services, api, ember.js, ember-data

I have been working on a web app using .NET web forms. Now I'm trying to move to a Web API and a client side application. I'm trying to use Ember.js right now. I'm starting to get confused with Ember 2.0, Ember-Data and stuff.

My problem right now is that I'm trying to consume some of the REST services in order to show a list of things in my Ember app. Is it mandatory for me to use Ember-Data? If not, how can I consume the services to create, read, update and delete items (I mean, am I able to use only ajax or something)?

The Web API was built in order to be usable for many technologies. I need to build an specific URL for each request (even a simple GET has some mandatory parameters). That's why ember-data is not working well for me, at least not what I have learnt about it. Because `this.store.find` won't allow me to build the URL I need.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it mandatory for me to use Ember-Data?

No, it's not. You can use other libraries such as [Ember RESTless](https://github.com/bustlelabs/ember-restless), or write your own.

You can even use simple jQuery AJAX calls whenever you need to fire a request to your API, however, you'll loose many benefits of Ember Data, such as lazy, asynchronous loading of models when they are needed.

> That's why ember-data is not working well for me, at least not what I
>   have learnt about it. Because this.store.find won't allow me to build
>   the URL I need.

You can override `buildURL` method of adapter you're using(for example RESTAdapter), source code on GitHub could be helpful if you would like to do that, and you can find everything you need to create your own behavior for `buildURL` method in [Ember API documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm having a lot of problems trying to overrides Ember Data methods because:
1. My API doesn't have the object root structure, I had to override some serializer methods, but at the end I couldn't get it to work.
2.My API is paginated (I don't know if the word is correct), so in every request I have to specify a page size and a page number. If I have 1000 registers, I can get 100 at most per page. I think it won't suit well with ember-data. What do you think?

Comment: It could be complicated but if you would split logic across custom serializers and adapters it could work. Ember Data allows for flexibility. But yeah, it might require some work and headaches to do that.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, very much!